# Extension for zooming webpage by regex

Tags: web-browser, regex, zoom

I want to zoom all sites with URL `*.stackexchange.com` to 120%, all sites with URL `*.wikipedia.org` to 130%. Is there a way to do so? So far I have to individually zoom each specific page, and it's frustrating.

I have tried [Zoom Browser Extension](https://www.stefanvd.net/project/zoom/browser/index.htm), but it doesn't zoom individual page with this setting:

[image]

I have to use the closest alternative, which is to set the default zoom to 120%:

[image]

But there are pages that I prefer to not be zoomed at all.

Is there an extension better than this? I use Vivaldi and Firefox 52.

Comment: Hi Ooker, sorry the extension didn't work for you after SOX :( Just to clarify, do you want to be able to have different zoom levels for different pages on the _same_ domain (and hence the regex support)? If so, I could try making a (very simple) one if nobody knows of one that already exists!

Comment: hey there. No, I just want to have one zoom level for every page on the same domain. The regex is just to support the `*` symbol, because I think, why not make it a regex? Perhaps someone will really need one.

Comment: Ah fair enough! I think the Zoom extension should work for each specific domain then, does 'zoom at domain' level not work?

Comment: I think it's because it doesn't accept asterisk in the URL, and require `https://` at the start, so I'm forced to use the specific URL (`writing.stackexchange.com`, `academia.stackexchange.com`), which is basically useless